# How to spilt a files into chunks and store no.of chunks,file name and size to json?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to automate this proces with linux shell script(bash script)
eg:

```
afile.txt
bfile.txt
cfile.txt
dfile.txt
efile.txt
ffile.txt
gfile.ps1
```

only .txt files to be divided into chunks of 1000bytes
eg:

```
afile.txt00
afile.txt01
afile.txt02
```

after that need to create a json containing like

**{"avaible_files":[["afile.txt",2056,"1.0",3],["bfile.txt",948,"2.0",1],["cfile.txt",1054,"1.001",2],["dfile.txt",3085,"3.0",4],["efile.txt",9685,"1.0.0",10],["efile.txt",6985,"1.0.2",7],["dfile.txt",65,"1.0.0",1],["ffile.txt",9996,"3.1.0",10],["gfile.txt",785,"2.0.0",1]]}**

in the json, data format is [file name,size,version,chunks]
Here version is hard coded text written inside the .txt file

```
    function M.version()
      return "1.0"
    end
```

please help me writing bash script that will do this job
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is the first part:

`ls *.txt | while read FILE; do split -b 1000 -d $FILE $FILE; done`

Second part is less clear to me...

Comment: second part is to create json will contain filename, size, version, no.of chunks                     Eg:  {"avaible_files":[["afile.txt",2056,"1.0",3],["bfile.txt",948,"2.0",1],["cfile.txt",1054,"1.001",2],["dfile.txt",3085,"3.0",4],["efile.txt",9685,"1.0.0",10],["efile.txt",6985,"1.0.2",7],["dfile.txt",65,"1.0.0",1],["ffile.txt",9996,"3.1.0",10],["gfile.txt",785,"2.0.0",1]]}

Comment: version feild is the data inside the file that is function M.version()
      return "1.0"
    end

Comment: used this command grep -rs -A1 version .| awk '/return/ {print $                            response is                                                                                                               ./afile.txt-"1.0"
./bfile.txt-"2.0"
./cfile.txt-"1.0.0.1"
./dfile.txt-"3.0"
./efile.txt-"1.0.0"
./ffile.txt-"1.0.2"
./gfile.txt-"2.0.0"